# Security Cameras Don't Display Video Despite Proper Hookup?

Tags: security

My parents purchased a camera system more than a decade ago, and they called someone over to (do something with them? They don't remember...)

Anyway, the result was that almost all of the cameras went down.

They all have power, but there is no video stream from them. They light up with their infrared LED's at night, but after checking the DVR's settings, they have no video feed coming to the DVR (This was also checked by directly wiring the camera to a TV with no DVR in between them).

Additionally, I pulled one of the cameras down and brought it to my TV and gave it power (DC 12V from my power supply), and wired it directly to the TV (No DVR in between to rule out DVR issues).

It had no video feed.

Could all of the cameras have died over time (Which seems wildly implausible to me, they are *exterior* cameras), or am I missing something? My mom said that the person who was called over was adjusting the cameras physically and might have turned them off somehow, but upon inspection of the cameras, there is no such switch.

Here is the make/model of the camera:

Are the cameras viable, or should I get a new set of cameras?
[image: Camera]

Comment: What type of cable & connector is used for the video?

Comment: @SolarMike It uses a combination of BNC and DC12.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why the person can't be called back? They would know what they have done.  ( Was it someone they don't know who approached them door to door unsolicited? If so, knockong out the cameras was Act I... Act II will be a burglary.)

Comment: "almost all of the cameras went down"  Take one that didn't go down and try hooking it up to your tv to make sure your test method is valid.

Comment: @JACK The testmethod is valid because I successfuly viewed a test camera already :)

Comment: Then they are all dead time to replace but better res and night vision in many cases are cheaper today than old low res. A ring camera has better quality cheaper price than these antique types are you still using a CRT monitor? Just wondering.

Comment: @EdBeal No, it's a digital computer monitor that is using a BNC to HDMI converter. I verified that this works with a working camera.

Answer (score 1):

You should get new cameras. A Google search on the item number came up with nothing. As they are over 10 years old they may just have died of old age. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Most cameras that old are composite video so if you don’t have them in the proper input to your tv you will not get a signal with a perfectly functional camera. The fact that multiple cameras went down would me looking for what is common in the system. Some units use video splitters so multiple cameras or just a single view can be viewed based on what is selected, this can be the function of a DVR that has multiple inputs. I have changed even my home system over to digital high res because composite is becoming obsolete and the digital models have much better night vision and higher resolution. So check the common component it may have failed or something simple like the power supply that runs the splitter or dvr may be the cause, having multiple cameras die at the same time with no other electrical failures would be extremely rare.

Comment: I made sure that they were in the correct input to the TV, and tested it using a working camera. The voltage coming off the power supply is 11.93V at the camera location.

Comment: Ok then I have no help replace all your cameras but for 2 or more to fail At the same time maybe 2 with a lighting strike or some other big surge but if more than 2 cameras went down the chances diminish that it it is a camera problem but something else but I only support about 50 cameras and a dozen DVR’s so I am a amateur.  At a minimum purchase 1 new one and see if you can get it to work any place. I have a small monitor I can wear like a wrist watch and check where my cameras are pointed with both digital and composite models, it is a great troubleshooting tool, but you had a test ?

Comment: That is what I said. Probability theory suggests that something else happened, but fundamentally, if power is directly supplied to the camera and it's wired directly to the monitor, it should display output, no questions asked. When I do this with a working camera, it works. Don't know what's going on, maybe it has some kind of "off mode" I don't know about?